# Alternate ring tunes on SMSs and Phone calls on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I would like to randomize phone call rings and received SMS sounds. I would have a list of about 5 or so ring tones, and whenever an SMS is received or there's an incoming phone call I would like to randomly select a sound which is played.

Is this possible? If so, can anyone recommend any articles or tutorials on how to get started with this? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Each of the application you develop is some kind of sandboxed and you can't modify the behaviour of system components like switching ringtones. That would be a security issue.